# What is the meaning of the sysContact object in snmpd.conf?

Tags: linux, snmp, snmpd

I have the following snmpd.conf file in my linux machine

```
rocommunity blmlom 127.0.0.1
rocommunity blmlom hty.corp
rocommunity blmlom  hty.corp
syscontact totadmin@hju.com
syslocation UNKNOWN
trapcommunity blmlom
trapsink  hty.corp blmlom
```

what is the meaning of `sysContact` in the file? What is good for ?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27352479/1704582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syscontact is a value that can be retrieved via SNMP.  It may be useful to get this data via SNMP, on the other hand it may just be an information leak or a value that is going to quickly go stale.

Organizationally you have to decide if you want to use SNMP as a way of determining a contact for the host, or not.

Syscontact has no other effect.

You'd most likely see this value used where a central SNMP poller attempts to discover all devices on the network, and uses this to categorize the host or configure alerting.